# Subset Columns in R using which

Tags: r

I have a 1 row dataframe called ff, I want to select which columns are greater than a certain value (2.5).

I was trying this:

```
ColContribs <- ff[which(ff[,1:ncol(ff)]>2.5),]
```

It's not working, I know this is simple, what am I doing wrong..?

Paul.

Comment: Try this: `ff[,ff[1,] > 2.5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is that you are using the condition `which(ff[,1:ncol(ff)]>2.5)` to choose rows (we know that there is only a single row) rather than columns. Hence,

```
ff[, which(ff[,1:ncol(ff)]>2.5)]
```

would work. Or simply

```
ff[, ff > 2.5]
```

Comment: I get this when i run both ........data frame with 0 columns and 1 row .....even though I can see ff has 1obs with 66 vars

Comment: @PaulBeales, then there are no columns satisfying this conditions. Just add your data to the question (with `dput`) and it will become clear.

Comment: ok...I'm being really stupid - it should have been 0.25 not 2.5